# How to designate a window to be the target for all links in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm trying to create a setup where I have 2 windows in the left side of the frame, containing Org-mode buffers, and a big window on the right side of the frame, which I want to be the target for all the links in the left side buffers.

How do I force Org-mode links to open in that right side window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
M-: (set-window-dedicated-p (selected-window) t)
```

on the windows you want to remain unchanged.